# How to make the last slide be the same as the first one?

Tags: beamer

I would like to repet the first slide in order to use it at the last one. I could do it with some pdf editor but I would prefer to do it directly with latex.

Comment: Hi.  In case you aren't aware, you could do this with a PDF editor such as `pdftk` in a *batch file*.  I'm telling you this in case you thought the pdf editor route would have to involve hands-on GUI work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `etoolbox` with the command `\AtEndDocument` seems to work as required.

```
\documentclass[t,10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title{Title of the talk}
\author{Some X. Author}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\AtEndDocument\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
Another text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This would work for a title page, but what if the OP's first page is a bunch of paragraphs, formulas, and figures?

Comment: @James: I know. However, I'm assuming that most serious talks start always with the requisities such as the title of the talk (realized by `\maketitle`) and the name of the speaker. Anyway, I'll think about your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @James: Simply put the whole `frame`-environment as the argument of `\AtEndDocument`.

Comment: So does that mean you would have to repeat all of the frame contents?  I'm not a `beamer` user, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @James: The OP mentions the "slide" (hence, the whole frame probably). But if we consider only a subset of the frame, they are certainly ways based on `\immediate\write`. However, there are also much easier ways.

Comment: I don't think my question was clear.  How would the OP use `\atEndDocument` to typeset a frame at two different places in the document without having to type the frame contents twice?

Comment: @James: Simply define the command `\twice` as `\def\twice#1{#1\AtEndDocument{#1}}`. After `\begin{document}` you can write `\twice{\begin{frame}...\end{frame}}`.

Comment: That's cool!  Thanks.

Comment: You could also label frames and use `\againframe` instead of the environment.